How to Calculate Price Impact on Uniswap V3 and SushiSwap in Go?
I’m currently building a trading bot on the Ethereum network using Go. I’m retrieving data from Uniswap V3 and SushiSwap via their APIs, and I’m struggling with calculating the price impact correctly.
For Uniswap V3, I have access to the following data points from the API:

sqrtPrice
liquidity
token0Price
token1Price

For SushiSwap (similar to Uniswap V2), I can retrieve:

reserve0
reserve1
token0Price
token1Price

I know that for SushiSwap, using the constant product formula x * y = k, I can derive the price impact by simulating the change in reserves before and after the trade. However, I’m having trouble applying this method to Uniswap V3 because it uses a different pricing model based on sqrtPrice and liquidity.
I would like to calculate the price impact for both Uniswap V3 and SushiSwap using the data provided by their APIs.
My specific questions are:

How can I derive the token reserves from Uniswap V3’s sqrtPrice and liquidity values?
How should I calculate the price impact once I have the reserves or any other necessary values?

I’d appreciate any examples or detailed explanations, particularly in Go if possible, as that’s the language I’m working with.
So far, I’ve attempted two different approaches to calculate the price impact for Uniswap V3:

Direct calculation using sqrtPrice and liquidity: I tried calculating the price impact by simulating the trade directly using the provided sqrtPrice and liquidity. However, this often led to incorrect or extreme values, such as a price impact of -100%, especially for pools with low liquidity or invalid sqrtPrice.
Deriving reserves from sqrtPrice and liquidity: I also attempted to calculate the token reserves from these values and apply the same method used in SushiSwap, but this didn’t yield accurate results either, likely due to the differences in how Uniswap V3 handles pricing.

Despite these efforts, I haven’t been able to match the results shown on actual dApps. Any guidance on how to correctly calculate the price impact for both Uniswap V3 and SushiSwap would be greatly appreciated.

On Uniswap v3 you can directly ask their quoter smart contract for a price impact.

Here is a Python example how to call Uniswap v3 quoter - Go code should be the same


How can I derive the token reserves from Uniswap V3’s sqrtPrice and liquidity values?

You cannot because you do not know the shape of the liquidity and individual ranged liquidity positions represented as NFTs.

How should I calculate the price impact once I have the reserves or any other necessary values?

The other necessary values includes the state of the CLMM liquidity in Uniswap v3 pool and this is very difficult to extract out from Ethereum VM state. It's just easier to call the quoter smart contract directly.
SushiSwap is equivalent of Uniswap v2 and you can find plenty of examples how to calculate price for Uniswap v2, including here in tutorials.
Also technically these are "ABIs" (application binary interface) which is just the symbol dump on the smart contract code. API is what you call to your JSON-RPC node.
